# VB.NET Multiline Datagrid value to textbox (shows one line in textbox)

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, textbox, multiline

I have a DataGridView in my project, which has 4 columns and data loaded from XML file - one of columns contains multiline SQL script, on double click this query should be copied to multiline textbox.

As You can see here:
[My Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxBQ1.png)

[image]

In DGV it looks like multiline but to textbox it's copied as one ugly and not-readable line...

I'm using this to copy cell value to textbox (on doubleclick):

Query_TextBox.Text = DataGridView2.Item("QueryData", DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Index).Value

Multiline and WordWrap properties of TextBox are set as True. I tried to set: Me.DataGridView2.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True and: "AcceptsReturn=True" for TextBox, But still no luck.

I tried to append some multiline text to textbox like: 
TextBox.Text="asdasd  
asdasdads  
asdads" 
and it worked... Problem exists only when I'm trying to show data from DGV in TextBox...

Maybe problem is with data loading? I'm using: 
Dim reader As New System.IO.StringReader(My.Resources.Library) 
(...)
ds.ReadXml(reader) DataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

How can I copy it as a multiline string to textbox?

Comment: Welcome to SO Matti,  are you using WinForms?

Comment: Hello :) Yes, I'm using WinForms.

Comment: Maybe problem is with data loading?
I'm using:

Dim reader As New System.IO.StringReader(My.Resources.Library)
(...)
ds.ReadXml(reader)
DataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by replacing simple TextBox by RichTextBox. It started to show all the 'new line' characters correctly :)

Thank You all for engagement.

Answer (score 0):

I believe setting `Multiline` and `WordWrap` properties of the textbox to `true` should do the work.

Comment: I have this property set like this, but it doesn't help... :(

Comment: What about the `WordWrap` property? It should also be set to true according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: WordWrap property of TextBox is also set as True.
I tried to set: Me.DataGridView2.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
But it also didn't help...

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know what else to try... When you enter text manually does it behave like a multiline text box?

Comment: Yes, I tried to append some multiline text to textbox like:
TextBox.Text="asdasd <enter, or: & Environment.NewLine>
asdasdads <enter, or: & Environment.NewLine>
asdads"
and it worked...
Problem exists only when I'm trying to show data from DGV in TextBox...

Comment: Good idea, perhaps someone can answer this now. If you can edit your question to provide the info of this thread, so others who won't read these comments still have the information they need.

Comment: Although you can repeat your test without giving newline characters and see if the text is properly wrapped.